# Django include template show no data

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to include a html file, into my course page , but when i add the code it show just first tag that is h3 and don't show other data why ?

the code : `{% include 'android/side_bar_good_posts.html' %}`

- note : i have added this code in other pages in my website and it work and show all data but in this page course it don't show anything else ( most read articles ) word

Comment: please provide that template

Comment: Did you passed context in course page?

Comment: @ManojTolagekar check this , my code https://newtextdocument.com/t/side_bar_good_posts

Comment: @AnkitTiwari do you mean in view.py ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari thanks broooo , it's work now , i forget add it to view